# Difference between $1+o(1)$ and $1-o(1)$

Tags: limits, asymptotics

The question is about [Little o notation](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Big_O_notation). In the book [Asymptopia by Joel Spencer, section 2.3](https://bookstore.ams.org/stml-71), it is stated that $1+o(1)$ is a term that approaches 1. If $h(n)=1+o(1)$, then with arbitrarily small positive $\epsilon$, we must have $1-\epsilon \leq h(n) \leq 1+\epsilon$, for all sufficiently large n.

Also Endre Szemeredi's paper [Embedding graphs into larger graphs:
results, methods, and problems, remark 1.1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.02068.pdf) mentions that

> since $A(n) + o(n)$ and $A(n)−o(n)$ mathematically are exactly the same, we shall be cautious with formulating some of our theorems.

It seems to me that $1+o(1)$ and $1-o(1)$ are the same quantity. So why some theorems explicitly use the latter term?

Comment: If $ f(x) $ goes to zero, minus $f(x)$ goes to minus zero$=0$.

Comment: There is a chance that, while they do represent the same class of functions, in context a theorem might deal with functions that converge to $1$ from some side -- as in, $o(1)$ might temporarily mean *positive* functions that converge to $0$.  I'm not sure how you could tell when this is happening in general except by understanding the proof of the given theorem.

Comment: Using $o(1)$ notation removes information about the sign of the quantity being replaced. I guess in some cases writing $-o(1)$ can be a suggestive indication that the quantity [that tends to zero] is negative, but strictly speaking the definition of $o(1)$ doesn't allow one to discern this, as you and the author pointed out. To make this clear, the author must be "cautious with formulating."

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah I don’t understand the comment. Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @angryavian thank you for clearing that up

Comment: Hi. $o(1)=\epsilon(x)=-\epsilon'(x)=-o(1)$